# ListView of Xamarin Forms for Android and Arrows of keyboard

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have developed a Xamarin forms app for Android and I have a listview and one of devices where I test it has a keyboard, so I use the device with arrow in order to control instead the mouse. But the app that I have developed, doesn’t work with keyboard.

Do you know what should I do in order to work with arrow in order to select item of listview?

Thank you

Comment: By default use hardware keyboard with arrow will highlight the focused listview item, and then press "enter" key will select this item.

Comment: Thanks Grace but it doesn't happen. Could you tell me where a sample of xamarin forms listview where I can try it and search differences between sample and my app?

Comment: Try this: [Xamarin.Forms ListView Sample: Custom Cells](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/CustomCells)?

Comment: I have built it and I have deployed on devices and I can see the focused ítem when I click with mouse, but I can't see the focused ítem when I try to change the selection with keyboard arrows. And I have tryed again on my app, and I have seen the focus once time on banner ads where I have been able to close ads in order to get other banner. But I can't get the focus on listview ítem :(

Comment: In order to discard problems with my device and keyboard, I have developed a basic listview on Android studio and arrows of keyboard work correctly. Then, I have developed a basic listview of Xamarin Android and it works. So why does not it work with Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Could it be a bug? Because other elements as stack, buttons,.. work correctly with keyboard.